# ASP.Net Passing Object To View With A Parameter Set To A List of Another Object Filtered By Matching IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently working in ASP.NET with Entity Framework and I am dealing with two model objects, called "Game" and "Review".

"Review" has a property called "GameId"

"Game" has a property called "Reviews" which is an ICollection intended to hold a collection of "Review" where "GameId" matches the "Game"s "Id".

I am in the "GamesController" trying to pass a "Game" to the "Detail" view where the details of "Game" will be displayed, including the list of "Review" that match.

This is my current code.

```
///Controller Code///
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{    
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Game game = db.Games.Find(id);

    game.Reviews = db.Reviews.ToList().Where(r => r.GameId == game.Id) as ICollection<Review>;

    if (game == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(game);
}
///End Controller Code///


///View Code///
@model GameReviewApp.Models.Game

//snipped irrelevant code//

@foreach (var item in Model.Reviews)
{
    <p>@item.Content</p>
}

///End View Code///
```

When running this code I get the following error when i try to load up the "Detail" page and display the list of "Review"

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

From what I can see, after my LINQ filter, the `ICollection` isn't getting populated and it's being left null. I've double checked my database and I know there are 2 entries that should end up in the list were the filter to work properly. Any advice?

Comment: `game.Reviews = db.Reviews.Where(r => r.GameId == game.Id).ToList();` (your current query returns `IEnumerable<Review>`, not `ICollection<Review>` therefore it cannot be cast and is `null`. And if you have set up your relationship properties correctly, then all you need is `Game game = db.Games.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);` anyway. And your `if (game == null)` would need to go before `game.Reviews = db.Reviews....` anyway - you would have already thrown an exception

Comment: you have to add the ToList() function at the end of the Linq sintaxis to transform it to List of Review's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to cast the IEnumerable returned by LINQ to an ICollection - because the cast fails, `game.Reviews` will be null every time.

The below code should work for you:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {    
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Game game = db.Games.Find(id);

        if (game == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        game.Reviews = db.Reviews.Where(r => r.GameId == game.Id).ToList();            

        return View(game);
    }
```

You can use `.ToList()` instead of `as ICollection<Review>`, which should successfully achieve what you're going for.

I'd also recommend removing the `.ToList()` from `db.Reviews.ToList()`, as it retrieves every `Review` from the database and puts them in memory, and here you're only interested in `Reviews` with a matching `GameId`.

EDIT: As has been mentioned, your nullcheck for `game` should also come immediately after resolving the object.

Comment: Thanks a whole ton for the helpful response! This is actually for a course in ASP.NET I'm taking and a lot of the components of .NET, such as using LINQ, are things I've never really worked with much before, so I was quite confused.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize game.Reviews

```
    objGame.Reviews = new Icollection<Review>();
    //or

    Game objGame= new Game(){
    Reviews=new ICollection<Review>()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If games and reviews have a proper relationship defined, it should have been loaded by lazyloading and you don't need the second query.Otherwise just put a null check after this

```
Game game = db.Games.Find(id);

if (game != null)
{
    game.Reviews = db.Reviews.Where(r => r.GameId == game.Id).ToList();
}
```